# How do I add autofocus to my spring form input?

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, autofocus

`<div>
<sf:input type="text" cssClass="xxsLen" id="field1" maxlength="3" path="Data.field1"/>
</div>`

I have more  but I want to add autofocus to the first one. How do I do it here? I tried adding auto focus at the end but it breaks my code. Also this is a .jsp file.

Comment: What you are asking? What you tried so far?

Comment: somehow it didn't show my code that I entered. This is my first time using stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Spring version is remotely modern, you can add your own attributes. You need proper XHTML though, so try this:

```
<sf:input type="text" cssClass="xxsLen" 
    id="field1" maxlength="3" path="Data.field1" autofocus="autofocus" />
```

Comment: I did this method. When I refresh or load the page I see the text field highlighted for a second but the it looses focus automatically.